# Запрет на ввод определенных слов в textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

Как с помощью jQuery запретить ввод определенных слов в `textarea`?
Необходимо для предотвращения ввода нецензурных выражений.

Comment: Целесообразнее такие вещи делать на стороне сервера. Клиентская часть открыта для изменения пользователю.

Answer (score 3):

Ну как-как, проверять каждое введенное слово на слово "паразит", но есть куча но!

можно писать слова паразиты с пробелами, заменять буквы числами,писать со звездочками, с повторами букв, менять русские буквы на английские или другие, и многое-многое другое. Геморроя много лучше поискать какие-нибудь уже готовые решения.

Можно использовать регулярки, но бывают слова, которые попадут в бан такие как

**блоха** слово **лох**

**тра*аться**  это кстати ни разу не матерное слово, это значит удариться в первом приближении, но его все употребляют иначе(но запикаю его) :)

ну я так к примеру, и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Да-да. Даже алгоритм используемый в WoW, запикивал имя одного из квестовых персонажей "Змеебой" -> "Зме**ой" )

Comment: вот-вот, и я о чем, тут как вариант писать обучаемый скрипт, но и проверять его постоянно чему он научился, а это еще куча подводных камней в мутной воде.